# $\sum _{k=1}^n\:\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\cdot k\cdot \pi }{n}\right)-2\:+\:i\cdot \sin\left(\frac{2\cdot k\cdot \pi }{n}\right)\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, trigonometric-series

$\sum _{k=1}^n\:\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\cdot k\cdot \pi }{n}\right)-2\:+\:i\cdot \sin\left(\frac{2\cdot k\cdot \pi }{n}\right)\right)$

Normally the general factor is $a(n)=\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi }{n}\right)-2+i\cdot \sin\left(\frac{2k\pi }{n}\right)$

All I was able to do to the sum above was rewrite it as:

$\sum _{k=1}^n\:\left(\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi }{n}\right)\right)\:+\:\sum _{k=1}^n\left(i\cdot \sin\left(\frac{2k\pi }{n}\right)\right)\: - 2n$

Expecting the sums to cancel each other out and a result of something around -2n but not sure how to do that.

Comment: Well, the terms under the last summation will look much better in exponential form.

Comment: Remember https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: @Macavity means to transform the two sums in a sum of e^i*2kpi/n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S = \sum_{k =1}^n\left[\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)\right]$$

Consider vectors in complex plane:
[image]

- Analytical
  $$\begin{align*}S 
  &= \sum_{k =1}^n\left[\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)\right] = \sum_{k =1}^ne^{i\frac {2k\pi}{n}}\\
  & =\frac {e^{i(2\pi + \frac {2\pi}{n})}-e^{i(\frac {2\pi}{n})}}{e^\theta-1} =0 \text{ :Numerator = 0}\\
  \end{align*}$$

$$\implies \sum _{k=1}^n\:\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\cdot \:k\cdot \pi }{n}\right)-2\:+\:i\cdot \:\sin\left(\frac{2\cdot \:k\cdot \pi }{n}\right)\right) = -2n$$

Comment: Great answer! Thank you